# Annotating maximum by iterating each rows and make new column with resultant output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Annotating maximum by iterating each rows. and make new column with resultant output.
Can anyone help using pandas in Python, how to get the result?

```
         text      A      B      C
index                     
0        Cool     False  False   True
1        Drunk     True  False  False
2        Study     False  True  False


Output:
        Text      Result   
index                     
0       Cool       False  
1       Drunk      False  
2       Study      False
```

Comment: How do you get your output? What is "Result"? What "maximum" are you trying to get?

Comment: Dataframe, I tried using this : df['Result'] = df.max(axis= 1)

Comment: I want to get the iterate over rows and check if False comes maximum, or True comes maximum, whichever is max, output should be that value in a new column

Comment: Can you post a better example where there are actually different values in "Result" column?

Comment: "check if False comes maximum, or True comes maximum" Meaning you want the Result to be the value (True or False) with the highest frequency per row? Like `df['new_col'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].agg(pd.Series.mode, axis=1)`?

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of each row is more than half the length of the columns, `True` is the more common value.

Try:

```
df["Result"] = df.drop("text", axis=1).sum(axis=1)>=len(df.columns)//2+1
output = df[["text", "Result"]]

>>> df
    text  Result
0   Cool   False
1  Drunk   False
2  Study   False
```